# Ajuda com JOINS em 3 tabelas

Tags: php, html, mysql

Eu encontrei um tutorial falando sobre JOINS e implantei na pesquisa pelas vendas realizadas.

Mas deu quase tudo certo, só que na hora da busca pelo código de venda, ao invés de me trazer somente o resultado referente ao código consultado, ele me traz o outro código e repetidos, e por varias vezes. Além de ficar dando loop.

Estou publicando abaixo o código usado para que os amigos possam dar uma analisada, e me dizer onde estou errando ou se falta algo.

```
<div align="left" style=" padding:2px; width:315px; height:auto; float:left;">
<label>Entre com o código da Venda</label>
<form action="prod_consulta_venda.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="busca" method="post">
<input size="6" type="text" value="" name="buscar"/>
    <input type="submit" name="busca" value="Buscar Venda"/>
</form>
    </div>
</div>

<div align="left" style=" padding:2px; width:1000px; height:auto; border-top:solid 2px; float:left;">

<br />

<?php
include 'conexao.php';

$buscar = $_POST['buscar']; 

$sql_listar = mysql_query("SELECT VENDA.codvenda, VENDA.codcliente, VENDA.datavenda, VENDA.total, ITEMVENDA.codproduto, ITEMVENDA.quant, ITEMVENDA.preco, CLIENTE.nome, CLIENTE.endereco, CLIENTE.bairro, CLIENTE.cidade, CLIENTE.estado, CLIENTE.cep FROM VENDA, ITEMVENDA, CLIENTE WHERE VENDA.codcliente = ITEMVENDA.codcliente = CLIENTE.codcliente LIKE '%$buscar%'");

$total_registros = mysql_num_rows($sql_listar);

if(mysql_num_rows($sql_listar) <= 0){
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
            alert("Desculpe! Nenhuma Venda foi encontrada com esse código!");
            window.location.href = "prod_consulta_venda.php";
            </script>';
    }else{

    while($res = mysql_fetch_array($sql_listar)){

    $conteudotabela1 .= '<tr style="color:#090;">

                <td align="center">'.$res['codvenda'].'</td>

                <td align="center">'.$res['codcliente'].'</td>

                <td align="center">'.$res['datavenda'].'</td>

                <td align="center">'.$res['total'].'</td>

                <td align="center">'.$res['codproduto'].'</td>

                <td align="center">'.$res['quant'].'</td>

                <td align="center">'.$res['preco'].'</td>

                <td align="center">'.$res['nome'].'</td>

                <td align="center">'.$res['endereco'].'</td>

                <td align="center">'.$res['bairro'].'</td>

                <td align="center">'.$res['cidade'].'</td>

                <td align="center">'.$res['estado'].'</td>

                <td align="center">'.$res['cep'].'</td>

            </tr>';
    }}

?>

<table class="tbllista" style="width: 15%">
    <thead>
        <tr align="center">
            <th style="width: 5%"></th>
            <th style="width: 5%">
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>

<table class="tbllista" style="width: 100%">
    <thead>
        <tr align="center">
            <th align="center">Cód. Venda</th>
            <th align="center">Cód. Cliente</th>
            <th align="center">Data da Venda</th>
            <th align="center">Total da Venda</th>
            <th align="center">Cód. Produto</th>
            <th align="center">Quantidade</th>
            <th align="center">Preço Unitário</th>
            <th align="center">Nome</th>
            <th align="center">Endereço</th>
            <th align="center">Bairro</th>
            <th align="center">Cidade</th>
            <th align="center">Estado</th>
            <th align="center">Cep</th>
         </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            <?php echo $conteudotabela1; ?>

    </tbody>
```

Comment: Tente usar um [outer join](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6441/6077).

Comment: Vou experimentar Patrick, se resolver eu publico o resultado, valeu? 
Mas eu editei o meu problema com uma solução no servidor local, mas esta me apresentando problema no servidor da Hospedagem. Se tu puderes dar uma analisada do porque ele fica dando loop direto te agradeço. Mas vou tentar com OUTER JOIN, quem sabe possa ser isso.

Answer (score 0):

Eu resolvi o problema com o INNER JOIN, usando o LocalHost do WampServer 2.5 funcionou certinho, trazendo o resultado correto referente a venda solicitada na busca.

Porém quando faço o FTP para o servidor, ele não funciona, fica dando loop direto.

Não entendi o porque que funciona no servidor local e não no da Hospedagem.

Estou publicando todo o código da página de busca, para que os amigos possam analisa-la e me dizer onde esta errado ou se falta alguma coisa para fazer ele rodar certinho.

```
<?php
include 'conexao.php';
?>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" />

<div align="center"  style="margin: 0 0 0 180px; max-width:1000px; width: 90%;">
<div align="left" style="margin:0 0 0 10px;"><h3>Consultar Venda</h3></div>

<div align="center" style=" padding:2px; width:655px; height:auto; float:left;">
    <div align="left" style=" padding:2px; width:315px; height:auto; float:left;">
        <label>Entre com o código da Venda</label>
            <form action="prod_consulta_venda.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="busca" method="post">
            <input size="6" type="text" value="" name="buscar"/>
            <input type="submit" name="busca" value="Buscar Venda"/>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div align="left" style=" padding:2px; width:1000px; height:auto; border-top:solid 2px; float:left;">

<br />

<?php
    include 'conexao.php';

$buscar = $_POST['buscar']; 

$sql_listar = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cliente
INNER JOIN venda
ON CLIENTE.codcliente = VENDA.codcliente
INNER JOIN itemvenda
ON CLIENTE.codcliente = ITEMVENDA.codcliente
WHERE VENDA.codvenda LIKE '%$buscar%'");

$total_registros = mysql_num_rows($sql_listar);

    if(mysql_num_rows($sql_listar) <= 0){
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
            alert("Desculpe! Nenhuma Venda foi encontrada com esse código!");
            window.location.href = "prod_consulta_venda.php";
            </script>';

    while($res = mysql_fetch_array($sql_listar)){

        $conteudotabela1 .= '<tr style="color:#090;">

                <td align="center">'.$res['codvenda'].'</td>

                <td align="center">'.$res['codcliente'].'</td>

                <td align="center">'.$res['datavenda'].'</td>

                <td align="center">'.$res['total'].'</td>

                <td align="center">'.$res['codproduto'].'</td>

                <td align="center">'.$res['quant'].'</td>

                <td align="center">'.$res['preco'].'</td>

                <td align="center">'.$res['nome'].'</td>

                <td align="center">'.$res['endereco'].'</td>

                <td align="center">'.$res['bairro'].'</td>

                <td align="center">'.$res['cidade'].'</td>

                <td align="center">'.$res['estado'].'</td>

                <td align="center">'.$res['cep'].'</td>

            </tr>';
    }}
?>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" />

<table class="tbllista" style="width: 15%">
    <thead>
        <tr align="center">
            <th style="width: 5%"></th>
            <th style="width: 5%">
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>

<table class="tbllista" style="width: 100%">
    <thead>
        <tr align="center">
            <th align="center">Cód. Venda</th>
            <th align="center">Cód. Cliente</th>
            <th align="center">Data da Venda</th>
            <th align="center">Total da Venda</th>
            <th align="center">Cód. Produto</th>
            <th align="center">Quantidade</th>
            <th align="center">Preço Unitário</th>
            <th align="center">Nome</th>
            <th align="center">Endereço</th>
            <th align="center">Bairro</th>
            <th align="center">Cidade</th>
            <th align="center">Estado</th>
            <th align="center">Cep</th>
         </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            <?php echo $conteudotabela1; ?>
    </tbody>
</div>
```

Estou deixando abaixo o endereço para verificarem o que esta acontecendo.

http://www.lccinformatica.com.br/prod_consulta_venda.php

Se alguém puder me dar uma ajuda, ficarei agradecido.

Obrigado pela atenção do todos.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido, eu estava esquecendo isso:

```
if(isset($_POST['busca'])){
```

no inicio do PHP, e as tabelas eu estava colocando-as em maiúsculas, e no BD elas estão em minusculas.

O código funcionando ficou assim:

```
<?php
include 'conexao.php';
?>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" />

<div align="center"  style="margin: 0 0 0 180px; max-width:1000px; width: 90%;">
<div align="left" style="margin:0 0 0 10px;"><h3>Consultar Venda</h3></div>

<div align="center" style=" padding:2px; width:655px; height:auto; float:left;">
    <div align="left" style=" padding:2px; width:315px; height:auto; float:left;">
        <label>Entre com o código da Venda</label>
            <form action="prod_consulta_venda.php" name="busca" method="post">
            <input size="6" type="text" value="" name="buscar"/>
            <input type="submit" name="busca" value="Buscar Venda"/>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div align="left" style=" padding:2px; width:1000px; height:auto; border-top:solid 2px; float:left;">

<br />

<?php
    include 'conexao.php';

    if(isset($_POST['busca'])){ //Estava faltando esta linha

$buscar = $_POST['buscar']; 

//As tabelas estavam em maiúsculas, e no BD elas estão em minusculas.
$sql_listar = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cliente
INNER JOIN venda
ON cliente.codcliente = venda.codcliente
INNER JOIN itemvenda
ON cliente.codcliente = itemvenda.codcliente
WHERE venda.codvenda LIKE '%$buscar%'")or die(mysql_error());

$total_registros = mysql_num_rows($sql_listar);

    if(mysql_num_rows($sql_listar) <= 0){

        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; URL= prod_consulta_venda.php'>
<script language='javascript'>
window.alert('Desculpe! Nenhuma Venda foi encontrada com esse código!');
</script>";

    }else{

    while($res = mysql_fetch_array($sql_listar)){

        $conteudotabela1 .= '<tr style="color:#090;">

                <td align="center">'.$res['codvenda'].'</td>

                <td align="center">'.$res['codcliente'].'</td>

                <td align="center">'.$res['datavenda'].'</td>

                <td align="center">'.$res['total'].'</td>

                <td align="center">'.$res['codproduto'].'</td>

                <td align="center">'.$res['quant'].'</td>

                <td align="center">'.$res['preco'].'</td>

                <td align="center">'.$res['nome'].'</td>

                <td align="center">'.$res['endereco'].'</td>

                <td align="center">'.$res['bairro'].'</td>

                <td align="center">'.$res['cidade'].'</td>

                <td align="center">'.$res['estado'].'</td>

                <td align="center">'.$res['cep'].'</td>

            </tr>';
    }}}     
?>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" />

<table class="tbllista" style="width: 15%">
    <thead>
        <tr align="center">
            <th style="width: 5%"></th>
            <th style="width: 5%">
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>

<table class="tbllista" style="width: 100%">
    <thead>
        <tr align="center">
            <th align="center">Cód. Venda</th>
            <th align="center">Cód. Cliente</th>
            <th align="center">Data da Venda</th>
            <th align="center">Total da Venda</th>
            <th align="center">Cód. Produto</th>
            <th align="center">Quantidade</th>
            <th align="center">Preço Unitário</th>
            <th align="center">Nome</th>
            <th align="center">Endereço</th>
            <th align="center">Bairro</th>
            <th align="center">Cidade</th>
            <th align="center">Estado</th>
            <th align="center">Cep</th>
         </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            <?php echo $conteudotabela1; ?>        
    </tbody>    
</div>
```

Bem é isso galera, agradeço a atenção de todos e espero ter contribuído, para ajudar a solucionar futuras duvidas em relação a esse caso.

Boas festas ,e abraço à todos.